# Rails change to_params url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have this overriding my to_params method in my model

```
  def to_param
    normalized_name = title.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]/, '')
    "#{self.id}-#{normalized_name}"
  end
```

and the URL shows like this `/posts/1-Hello-World-very-nice`
is it possible to make so that it shows like this `/posts/1/Hello-World-very-nice`

Comment: You can do this through routes (not to_param), but I am wondering "why?".  This goes against rails naming conventions. What are you trying to accomplish with this new url?

Comment: I messed up I didn't know you could be able to do this from rails routes.

Comment: I am glad that you got this working.  I am still wondering though... why would you want to do this?  I don't see the advantage of this over /posts/1-Hello-World-very-nice

Comment: I would think this would be better for SEO or that wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a separate route for this, for example:

In your routes file (assuming Rails 3):

```
match 'posts/:id/:name' => 'posts#show', :as => "show_post"
```

Then in your view you would need to use the following to generate the correct URL:

```
show_post_path(@post, :name => @post.normalized_name)
```

Note that the order in which you put this in your routes file is important, so that your other Post routes don't get overwritten.

Comment: I am trying this now but I am getting `undefined method `normalized_name' for #<Post:0x000001041c6038>` Where should I add the method to fix this?

Comment: Never find I fixed it I put `  def normalized_name
    self.title.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]/, '')
  end` in the Model